# Laravel/Composer not compliling all classes to compiled.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

After development locally and everything working, I went to push all new code which included a number of classes and models to the server. I proceeded to get an error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with
message 'Class 'photo' not found' in 
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/bootstrap/compiled.php:6114` error.
```

I've tried:

```
composer install
composer update
composer dumpautoload -o
php artisan optimize --force
php -dmemory_limit=1G artisan optimize -f
```

When I run `php artisan optimize --force`,

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 72 bytes) in 
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PHPParser/NodeAbstract.php 
on line 34
```

after composer returns `Compiling common classes` which led me to the `-dmemory_limit ...` command

I've uninstalled composer, deleted the vendor directory, removed the composer cache, deleting the compiled.php file and a number of other things and still cannot get around the initial Class Photo error. Everything is working fine locally with a similar LAMP setup. I'm at a loss for ideas. Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: The error message tells a different story. It says that compiled.php is still in sue. You write it would have been deleted. What is true now?

Comment: is it supposed to be class Photo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In my eloquent relationships I had the model names in lowercase. I'm not sure why this would be a problem on one server and not the other. This was only affecting 2 new models/classes, so just an oversight on my part.

So what I had before was:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('photo')->orderBy('sort', 'ASC');
}
```

and I changed it to:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Photo')->orderBy('sort', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: Class names in PHP are case-insensitive, but the class loading with an autoloader inherits the case sensitivity of the filesystem the files are located on. So when using lowercase classname in the code (not in the class definition), the autoloading will try to locate a lowercase filename. Using a precompiled file with the classes will declare such a class without autoloading it, and when a class named "Photo" is already declared, using it with `new photo()` will work, but this would break when using autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

It is good you resolved the issue yourself.But
I would like to through some light on why it runs on one server and not on other server.

**Windows server is case-insensitive** .Means photo and Photo are same..

But when you choose linux server the case is not like that.**Linux servers are case sensitive**.So photo is different from Photo..

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('photo')->orderBy('sort', 'ASC');
}
```

and changed it to:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Photo')->orderBy('sort', 'ASC');
}
```